# my change password forms error is not working in my html page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

my html form is

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <strong>{{message}}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <strong>{{error|escape}}</strong>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <strong>{{error|escape}}</strong>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

my views.py
when i enter wrong passwords its redirect me to same page , if i not return the else part of `is_valid` it giving me object return error.
what can i do for showing form error in frontend

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user , request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save
                update_session_auth_hash(request , user)
                messages.success(request , "Your password is successfully changed")
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.error(request , "Please correct the error below.")
                return redirect('change_password')
        else:
            form  = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
            return render(request , "change-password.html" , {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.error(request , "Please login to see that page")
        return redirect('login')
```

Comment: i did 's' in {% for error in field.error %} , but my problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing 's' at the end of this line `{% for error in field.error %}` should be `...in field.errors %}` in your template.

In views.py replace `redirect(view_name)` with:

`HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:view_name'))`

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user , request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save
                update_session_auth_hash(request , user)
                messages.success(request , "Your password is successfully changed")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:index'))
            else:
                messages.error(request , "Please correct the error below.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:change_password'))
        else:
            form  = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
            return render(request , "app_name/change-password.html" , {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.error(request , "Please login to see that page")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:login'))
```

You can also replace this function with class-based view:

```
#if user is not logged in 
#then will be redirected to the login page defined in settings.py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class YourViewName(PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = 'app_name/change-password.html'
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm #You can use custom form here
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app_name:index')

    #add these functions only if you want to add these messages 
    #to default Django messages
    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request , "Your password is successfully changed")

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request , "Please correct the error below.")

        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: i did it but my problem is not solved yet

Comment: @ManavPrajapati aren't you getting any errors in DEBUG mode? All I did in views.py was to replace redirect() function and I am seeing this message "Please correct the error below.".